# ios mapkit annotation clustering with callout

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, markerclusterer, callout

Currently I am trying to use the new clustering feature introduced in iOS 11.  However I am finding that when I use the clustering feature, I lose the functionality of my initial annotations including the callout and what happens when the annotation is clicked.  I believe it is because the I create the cluster in a different class than my annotations.  It seems as though with my current code I can have only one or the other.  Customized pins that don't cluster when you zoom out, or clustering pins with lost information.  Does anyone know of a better way to do this? Below I have attached code showing how I create the pin callouts and how I create clustering. Is there a way in which I can have both features?

Creating Callouts

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    // 2
    guard let annotation = annotation as? CalloutPin else { return nil }
    // 3
    let identifier = "Pin"
    var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView
    // 4
    if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
        view = dequeuedView
    } else {
        // 5
        view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    }
        return view
    }
    else{
        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin-annotation")

        annotationView.animatesDrop = true
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        return nil
    }

}
```

Code to create clustering

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class PinView :MKMarkerAnnotationView {
     override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
          //if let pin = newValue as? Pin {
           clusteringIdentifier = "pin"
           displayPriority = .defaultHigh

           //}
         }
     }
 }

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class ClusterView: MKAnnotationView {

   override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    displayPriority = .defaultHigh
    collisionMode = .circle
    centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -10) // Offset center point to animate better with marker annotations
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        if let cluster = newValue as? MKClusterAnnotation {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
            let count = cluster.memberAnnotations.count

            image = renderer.image { _ in
                // Fill full circle with tricycle color
                UIColor.red.setFill()
                UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)).fill()

                // Finally draw count text vertically and horizontally centered
                let attributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                   NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]
                let text = "\(count)"
                let size = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
                let rect = CGRect(x: 20 - size.width / 2, y: 20 - size.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height)
                text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)
            }
        }
    }
}
```